# Parse a value from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I was googling for 30 minutes but I didn't find anything that could help me.

My problem is that I'm trying to parse something from a string with RegExp. I'm normally a PHP developer and would use `preg_match_all()` for it, but since this doesn't exists in C# (oh really), I need something else.

Imagine I have this string:

```
string test = "Hello this is a 'test' a cool test!";
```

Now I want to get the thing that is inside single quotes (**'**) - in this example **test**.

Thanks in advance for helping me. Sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language! :/

Comment: Look at the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class. (Search for "C# regex match capture group" for examples/tutorials.)

Answer (score 2):

The C# way to do  `preg_match_all` is to use the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class and the `Match` method off of that.

Answer (score 2):

An easier, non reg-ex way of doing this:

```
string textInQuotes = String.Empty;
string[] split = test.Split('\'');
if (split.Length > 2) textInQuotes = split[1];
```

Comment: That should be `test.Split('\'')[1];`. Also, this is very unsafe, since it might throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the quotes do not exist.

Comment: @L.B It won't throw an exception, that's for sure. I think the answer is relevant. OP surely knows what to expect in input string and will, if required, need to implement fail-safe mechanisms whether he intents to use regular expressions or this approach.

Comment: @L.B I think Nikola is right but I made another edit to fix that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the example application code.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ExampleApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // This is your input string.
            string test = "Hello this is a 'test' a cool test!";
            // This is your RegEx pattern.
            string pattern = "(?<=').*?(?=')";

            // Get regex match object. You can also experiment with RegEx options.
            Match match = Regex.Match(test, pattern);
            // Print match value to console.
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it hepls!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex solution that allows for escaped delimiters withing the quoted portion of the text. If you prefer the *nix backslash style of escapes, simply replace the appropriate part of the Regex, `('')`, with `(\\')`.

```
static readonly Regex rxQuotedStringLiteralPattern = new Regex(@"
                 # A quoted string consists of
    '            # * a lead-in delimiter, followed by
    (?<content>  # * a named capturing group representing the quoted content
      (          #   which consists of either
        [^']     #   * an ordinary, non-delimiter character
      |          #   OR
        ('')     #   * an escape sequence representing an embedded delimiter
      )*         #   repeated zero or more times.
    )            # The quoted content is followed by 
    '            # * the lead-out delimiter
    "
    , RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture|RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    ) ;

public static IEnumerable<string> ParseQuotedLiteralsFromStringUsingRegularExpressions( string s )
{
  for ( Match m = rxQuotedStringLiteralPattern.Match( s ?? "" ) ; m.Success ; m = m.NextMatch() )
  {
    string raw    = m.Groups[ "content" ].Value ;
    string cooked = raw.Replace( "''" , "'" ) ;
    yield return cooked ;
  }
}
```